# apt-get maddeningly doesn't work with tsocks proxy set up with ssh

Tags: ssh, apt

I have a machine that cannot access the internet, yet can connect to a machine that does. I don't want to use a proxy server, I've been told that I can just use ssh. So I've proceeded simply by

```
ssh -D 1080 me@xxx.xx.xx.xx
```

I've confirmed that this works by doing

```
curl -v --socks5-hostname localhost:1080 http://google.com
```

This command returns expected HTML so it must be working.

I have changed my /etc/tsocks.conf to simply read:

```
server = 127.0.0.1
server_port = 1080
```

However, apt-get is having none of it;

```
# tsocks apt-get update
Err http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
etc
```

My /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I've been googling for a while, I tried adding the following to /etc/apt/apt.conf

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://localhost:1080/";
```

and not using tsocks at all, (I've tried it both ways), this makes it fail even faster.

I'm out of ideas, this should really work but doesn't. Any help?

Comment: An HTTP proxy is not a SOCKS proxy. So that would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with DNS.

Apparently, tsocks can't or won't resolve domain names.

I added to /etc/hosts the IP addresses of each of the domain names apt-get was trying to look for and tsocks magically worked.

Comment: Or instead of tsocks use proxychains